# How to ajax POST to php page and return output of PHP page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have the following code to ajax a POST request to my test.php file. I then want to load the output of the `test.php` into `<div id="here"></div>`.

My `test.php` file has the following:

```
var_dump($_POST);
die();
```

Here's the jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
    $('#here').find('a').on('click', function(e) // listens for <a href> click
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "test.php",
              data: { foo: "bar", working: "yes" }
            })
        $('#here').load('test.php');    // get the output of test.php
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm getting an empty $_POST array back from the test.php page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you paste code of test.php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it this way:

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "test.php",
          data: { foo: "bar", working: "yes" },
          success : function(response) {
               $('#here').html(response);
          }
        });
```

Because  `$.load()` method invokes a GET query by default. And also there's no point of calling ajax twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#here').find('a').on('click', function(e) // listens for <a href> click
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "test.php",
          data: { foo: "bar", working: "yes" },
          success: function(result){
                    $('#here').html(result);
             }
        })  
});
```

You need to add success function in your ajax to get the result